# Cannot reach $(this) from within $().data()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to set the class of my element inside a data object of the same element, but it keeps returning undefined.

```
$(this).data({
            orgSize:{ // Write all the sizes as data. For future reference.
                width: $(this).width(), //returns the width just fine!
                height: $(this).height() //returns the height just fine!
            },
            orgClass: function(){
                cl = $(this).attr('class');
                if(cl){
                    return ' ' + cl;
                }else{
                    return ' somethingelse';
                }
            } //returns undefined
        });

        console.log($(this).attr('class')) //returns the class
```

edit: The problem is within the orgClass.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var me = $(this);
me.data({
  orgSize  : { width:me.width(), height:me.height() },
  orgClass : function(){
    cl = me.attr('class');
    return cl ? (' '+cl) : ' somethingelse';
  }
});
```

Comment: Aside from the fact that this works, it also provides performance gains.  It's not smart for `$(this)` to appear multiple times in the same closure, you're running `jQuery.init()` over and over each time you do it.

Comment: To add to Phrogz answer, the reason the original code in the question does not work is 'this' changes based on the context of the function call (hard to say without seeing how it is being called).  Determining the value of 'this' is a common misunderstanding in JavaScript, and I highly recommend @dubbelj read up on it.  The reason this answer works is it captures the value of 'this' into what is called a 'closure', essentially locking in the value at the time of declaration.

Answer (score 0):

its a scope issue, 'this' inside 'orgSize' refers to the 'orgSize' object itself ..

Comment: It may be better to just vote up Phrogz instead of adding another post to the mix. :) Strengthens his response.

Comment: word. its just i'd written it anyway.. and maybe the first line is still relevant ? :)